# Is there a way to force read from disk in UcanAccess?

Tags: ucanaccess, jackcess

I'm building a Java app that needs to co-exist with a VBasic one. Both consume a single Access database (.mdb)

As sometimes the VB app writes the DB I'd need to programmatically re-read from disk the mdb. Is there a way to do this? is this Jackcess responsibility or Ucanaccess?

I'm using UcanAccess with Spring and Mybatis.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1):

UCanAccess always reloads the data when another process updates the db file